# Given a relation between $G$ and $g$ prove that $g(x)=x+1$.

Tags: calculus, integration

I am having several difficulties in solving an exercise that has been put to me.

The exercise says:

If $g: (-1; \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ is a function that can be antiderivated, let $G$ be the antiderivative of $g$ so that $$G(0)=\frac{1}{2}.$$ Supposing that $$(g(x))^2=2G(x),$$ then prove that $g$ is differentiable and $$\forall x>-1, g(x)=x+1.$$

I needed help trying to unblock the situation because I don't know how to start.

Best regards

Comment: By the fundamental theorem of calculus $G(x)$ is differentiable and its derivative from $0$ to $x$ is $g(x)$. Use this in $(g(x))^2=2G(x)$

Comment: Hint: $$
g(x) = \sqrt {2G(x)}  \Rightarrow g'(x) = \frac{{G'(x)}}{{\sqrt {2G(x)} }} = \frac{{g(x)}}{{\sqrt {2G(x)} }} = \frac{{g(x)}}{{g(x)}} = 1.
$$

Comment: @Gary $2gg'=2g$ derivation without resorting to square root is simpler. (at)OP: does $\mathbb R^+$ excludes zero ? If not we can only conclude by $G$ continuity that $g(x)=x+1$ in an interval $I$ containing zero and it can possibly be prolonged by constants outside.

Comment: @zwim You are correct. I just thought that in this way it is easier to see that $g$ itself is differentiable.

Comment: Ok. I see now how i can prove that g(x) is differentiable.

Comment: Ok. I see now how i can prove that g(x) is  differentiable. But how about província that g(x)=x+1? I Washington trying to use de primitive and make some kind of substitution to “make” appear the x but i’m not having luck...

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is the antiderivative (which exists) of $g$ that is to say $G'=g$. We also have that $G(0)=\frac12$ and $g^2(x)=2G(x)$

Firstly, we know that:
$$g(0)=\sqrt{2G(0)}=\sqrt{2(1/2)}=1$$

---

We can try differentiating the given equation:
$$2g(x)g'(x)=2G'(x)$$
$$2g(x)g'(x)=2g(x)$$
we get this from the first statement we made. Now as long as $g\ne 0$ we can divide through:
$$g'(x)=1$$
$$g(x)=x+C$$
now if we put in our condition for $g(0)$ we obtain:
$$g(x)=x+1$$
Hope this helps :)